# SharedPreferences or SQLite Database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-preferences

I'm writing a small alarm clock application, and I'm currently using SharedPreferences to store the settings for each alarm. I figured this would be more lightweight than using the SQLite Database, but now I'm thinking about writing a small thread-safe wrapper for SharedPreference. Am I being an idiot and should just use the database or would this still be more light-weight than the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For something this small, how lightweight it is isn't really relevant. Its a matter of 10 nanoseconds versus 50 nanoseconds (not literally but you get the idea). Just use what is easier and more reliable for your app

Comment: That's what I was originally thinking, but if I decide to use it for something bigger will there be any significant pros or cons?

Comment: Well that would depend on how big, but for something greater than 30 to 50 ish entries I would definitely switch to SQLite. Its just a better idea because it makes sorting and more complicated queries which you may at some point want easier. But thats just my opinion